# При установке Windows 7 в VirtualBox не видит жесткого диска

Tags: virtualbox, usb

Есть загрузочный USB. VirtualBox загружает ее если она указана как мастер. При этом второй диск не видит. Если указать как slave, пишет что начинает загружаться с флешки и все на этом. Больше ничего не происходит.

Comment: Скачай iso образ винды, при первом запуске virtualbox попросит выбрать образ для установки, указывай путь до образа. 100% работает, ни разу проблем не было

Comment: на работе скорость интернета ужасна....за целый день может не скачает. Так вчера пытался скачать...на каком-то моменте оборвала связь и пол дня на смарку. Протокол торрента закрыт. Дома записал загрузочную флэшку, а тут такая ерунда. Два дня уже потерял(((.

Comment: не ставь установщик винды на флешку, просто скопируй на нее iso файл

Comment: ах да, сделал iso-образ из usb, но VirtualBox его не прохавал: неверный формат.....а так да, завтра попробую записать просто iso-образ. Но что-то мне подсказывает, что и тут не обойдется без проблем.